# Powershell not importing functions from module

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-module, powershellget

I'm trying to setup a NuGet Feed here, and that worked ok. I installed a module from my feed via

```
Install-Module -Name MyCmdlets -Repository $RepoName -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Import-Module -Name MyCmdlets
```

However when I run Get-Module, I get no functions and it's a manifest?

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                  
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                  
Manifest   1.0        MyCmdlets
```

If I manually go to the installed location and import manually

```
Import-Module <my-path>\1.0\MyCmdlets.psm1                 

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                  
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                     
Script     0.0        MyCmdlets                      {Create-Project, Get-AuditLogs, Get-..
```

My manifest file does have these lines so I don't understand why `Import-Module` isn't working correctly.

> FunctionsToExport = '*'
>
> CmdletsToExport = '*'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you haven't set the root module in your .psd1 like so

```
#
# Module manifest for module 'YourModule'
#

@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest
RootModule = 'YourModule.psm1'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '1.0.0'

...
```

This is necessary so that when you import your manifest module it also loads the script module

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. I'll need to review the manifest files more in the future.

Comment: I knew that because I did the same a couple of weeks ago :D

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this looking for why their module wont import check that RootModule = 'YourModule.psm1' isn't commented out. 
By default when creating a new manifest using New-ModuleManifest it throws a hash in front of this line..

ugh I feel so stupid.